# CakePHP: testing -> ValidationException

Tags: cakephp, testing, phpunit

I'm new to programming and testing. I'm stuck at this testing, which throws an exception.
Please help me as I really don't get how I should approach this question.

My method to test:

```
public function saveNewInstitution($institutionData, $user) {
    $institutionData[$this->alias]['isActive'] = 1;
    $institutionData[$this->alias]['users_id'] = $user['User']['id'];
    $this->create();
    $this->set($institutionData);
    if ($this->validates()) {
        return $this->save();
    } else {
        throw new ValidationException('Not all fields are filled out correct');
    }
}
```

My testclass:

```
public function testSaveNewInstitution() {
    $result = array(
        'Institution' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Spitex',
            'address' => 'Hauptweg 4',
            'postcode' => '1234',
            'city' => 'huuh',
            'phone_number' => '123 456 78 90',
            'email' => 'staufen@tsdy.huuh',
            'comment' => '',
            'isActive' => TRUE,
            'users_id' => 2,
            'institution_types_id' => 5
        ),
        'Users' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'email' => 'herbert@xyz.ch',
            'password' => AuthComponent::password('12345678'),
            'isMale' => TRUE,
            'first_name' => 'Herbert',
            'last_name' => 'Müller',
            'address' => 'Hauptstrasse 1',
            'postcode' => '1234',
            'city' => 'Zürich',
            'phone_number' => '123 456 78 90',
            'isActive' => FALSE,
            'institutions_id' => 2,
            'groups_id' => 4
        ),
        'InstitutionTypes' => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'name' => 'Spitex'
        ),
        'Assignee' => array('0' => array(
                'id' => 2,
                'email' => 'herbert@xyz.ch',
                'password' => AuthComponent::password('12345678'),
                'isMale' => TRUE,
                'first_name' => 'Herbert',
                'last_name' => 'Müller',
                'address' => 'Hauptstrasse 1',
                'postcode' => '1234',
                'city' => 'Zürich',
                'phone_number' => '123 456 78 90',
                'isActive' => FALSE,
                'institutions_id' => 2,
                'groups_id' => 4
        ))
    );

    $expected = $this->Institution->saveNewInstitution($result, 2);
    $this->assertEqual($result, $expected);
}

public function testSaveNewInstitutionException() {
    $this->setExpectedException('ValidationException');
    $expected = array(
        'Institution' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Spitex',
            'address' => 'Hauptweg 4',
            'postcode' => '1234',
            'city' => 'huuh',
            'phone_number' => '123 456 78 90',
            'email' => 'staufen@xyz.huuh',
            'comment' => '',
            'isActive' => TRUE,
            'users_id' => 2,
            'institution_types_id' => 5
        ),
        'Users' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'email' => 'herbert@xyz.ch',
            'password' => AuthComponent::password('12345678'),
            'isMale' => TRUE,
            'first_name' => 'Herbert',
            'last_name' => 'Müller',
            'address' => 'Hauptstrasse 1',
            'postcode' => '1234',
            'city' => 'Zürich',
            'phone_number' => '123 456 78 90',
            'isActive' => FALSE,
            'institutions_id' => 2,
            'groups_id' => 4
        ),
        'InstitutionTypes' => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'name' => 'Spitex'
        ),
        'Assignee' => array('0' => array(
                'id' => 2,
                'email' => 'herbert@mueller.ch',
                'password' => AuthComponent::password('12345678'),
                'isMale' => TRUE,
                'first_name' => 'Herbert',
                'last_name' => 'Müller',
                'address' => 'Hauptstrasse 1',
                'postcode' => '1234',
                'city' => 'Zürich',
                'phone_number' => '123 456 78 90',
                'isActive' => FALSE,
                'institutions_id' => 2,
                'groups_id' => 4
        ))
    );
    $this->Institution->saveNewInstitution($expected, 2);
}
```

My exception:

```
**VALIDATIONEXCEPTION**
Not all fields are filled out correct
Test case: InstitutionTest(testSaveNewInstitution)
Stack trace:
/app/Test/Case/Model/InstitutionTest.php : 148
InstitutionTest::testSaveNewInstitution
/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php : 969
/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php : 824
/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php : 648
/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php : 769
/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestCase.php : 78
/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php : 775
/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php : 745
/usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php : 346
/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestRunner.php : 57
/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteCommand.php : 111
/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php : 242
/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php : 99
/lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php : 116
/app/webroot/test.php : 92
9/9 test methods complete: 8 passes, 0 fails, 12 assertions and 1 exceptions.
```

Comment: Apparently you are failing to meet your validation rules set in the `Institution` model.

Comment: Also, it might not be wise to throw exceptions here if you don't catch them anywhere. users will be pretty angry with you real soon if all validation errors trigger a 404 etc and they will have to to completely start from scratch with filling out your forms.

Comment: @mark: it is no problem as it is catched somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the comments, the issue is pretty straigt forward. your validation fails and therefore the exception is thrown (as desired by your code).

if you want to debug it, try to determine what

```
$this->validationErrors
```

contains after the save() (before/instead of throwing the exception). then you know why the validation fails.